# Firefox displaying username and password in all my forms?

Tags: php, html, firefox, forms

I have a website, and when I tell Firefox to remember my username and password for the website, it is causing the username and password to display in all forms on my website, such as registration form. It is only supposed to do this on the login form. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have given the form fields identical names, e.g. username/password. If you add this it will prevent the autofill:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="foo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with both firefox 3.6 and 5.0. Changing the field names did not prevent autocomplete, but 
  autocomplete='off'
did the trick(in both browsers). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the login form's input elements a different name.

> [FF] uses the usernamefield/password field values as hints to find the appropriate  elements within a webpage by matching them to the "name" attribute.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox%3aPassword_Manager

Comment: I am using firefox 3.6.15 and this doesnt seem to work.  I tried autocomplete="off" both in form and the password field.  Tried changing the name attribute of the pwd field to 'firstPass' but still firefox auto fills the pwd when i use tab on the username field (i tried changing the name of the username field too!)